# How to prove arraylist is not thread safe with a test?

Tags: java, arraylist, thread-safety

In our application we got an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception on the `ArrayList.add(Object o)` operation. The most obvious explanation is thread safety, but I wasn't able to recreate the events. I've tried creating two threads. In one I'm adding elements, in the other I'm removing them(or clearing the array), but I didn't get the exception for the second time. 
I mean it's obvious it can happen by looking at the source of ArrayList, but it would be nice to be able to demonstrate it.

I've been running this test for quite some time without any exception:

```
public class Test {
static ArrayList a = new ArrayList();

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Thread t1 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                if (a.size() > 0)
                    a.remove(0);
            }
        }
    };

    Thread t2 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                a.add(new Object());
            }
        }
    };

    t2.start();
    Thread.sleep(100);
    t1.start();
}
}
```

Comment: `ArrayList.add(Object)` won't throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`; `ArrayList.add(index, Object)` will.

Comment: guido: ```add(Object)``` can throw the exception as well(I saw it with my own eyes) if the inner state of the arraylist is changed from other thread. Check the source code.

Comment: yep you'are right: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.add%28java.lang.Object%29 ; it must be synchronized exernally

Comment: If multiple threads call ArrayList#add(Object) concurrently, it might happen due to race conditions! When the internal capacity value is already increased, but the internal storage array isn't (yet), another thread sees a non-full ArrayList and accesses the underlying array using an index out of bounds.

Comment: Look at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29

Comment: insnot2bad: Thanks. I was able to make a failing test:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to comment from isnot2bad I found a problem in my assumptions. 
The problem is with concurrent adds, not add/remove.
I was able to create a failing test:

```
static ArrayList a = new ArrayList(1);

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Thread t1 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                a.add(new Object());
            }
        }
    };

    Thread t2 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                a = new ArrayList(1);
                a.add(new Object());
                a.add(new Object());
            }
        }
    };

    t2.start();
    Thread.sleep(100);
    t1.start();
}
```

On the line with the add at the first thread, I'm getting this:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
```

:)

Comment: So better replace the `ArrayList` by a concurrent collection like `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` or simply `Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList())` in your project! ;)

Comment: In this particular case yes. I know where the problem is. But never saw that before.

Answer (score 2):

It can be hard to observe any error with the given code because you don't actually check what's stored in the list. I can't say it's impossible to get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` but it will be very rare because you can only get one when the array is being resized, and it is resized very seldom.

If you check that the objects that you remove are not duplicates it's much more probable to see unexpected behavior: you add only new objects, so the thread that removes should never see the same object twice, right? Not so:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test {
    static ArrayList a = new ArrayList();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Thread t1 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                Object x = null;
                while (true) {
                    if (a.size() > 0) {
                        Object y = a.remove(0);
                        if (x == y) System.out.println("Duplicate!");
                        x = y;
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        Thread t2 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    a.add(new Object());
                }
            }
        };

        t2.start();
        Thread.sleep(100);
        t1.start();
    }
}
```

This happens when an object is added during the `System.arrayCopy` call: `elementData[--size] = null` sets the wrong array index to `null` because `size` no longer has the value it had in the beginning of the method.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to reproduce your problem simply by adding more adder threads.

Answer (score 0):

Make your consumer thread sleep much less than the producer sleep, e.g. 20 ms instead of 100 ms. That way the chances of the exception to be thrown are much greater.

Comment: The threads are not sleeping. It's just a delay before starting the second thread. Anyway that code didn't produce the desired behavior